# matlab ticks with certain labels

Tags: matlab, label

I have the following part:

```
set(gca,'ylim',[0 0.3],'ytick',0:0.05:0.3);
set(gca,'xlim',[0 1],'xtick',0:0.05:1);
```

Ticks must remain as they are since when I enable the grid, ticks give me the grid resolution I want. What I also want is that I want to change the labels of x and y.

I want MATLAB to show all ticks but only show the following ticks' label:

`0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1.0` for x

`0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3` for y

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign labels to ticks using a cell array of strings, where each string corresponds to a tick. For ticks at which you don't want any label, use the empty string:

```
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'0','','','','0.2','','','','0.4','','','','0.6','','','','0.8','','','','1'})
set(gca,'yticklabel',{'0','','0.1','','0.2','','0.3'})
```