# Matlab change x axis tick label

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am relatively inexperienced with matlab, as I only use it occasionally. I am trying to plot a large range of values against time and I am running into some problems.

The data, which is from a text file, with about 55000 entries, gives the information in the following format:

year month day hour minute second value

The seconds column has accuracy of 6 decimal places and there are about 24hrs worth of data.

What I want to do is plot the values against time, which works fine. However as a result of my code below, the x-axis has label ticks in serial date number format, which is not very useful when looking at the figure. I want to change the labels to something more useful such intervals of hours. However I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Here is the code:

```
A = dlmread('data.txt',' ');
time = datenum(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),A(:,4),A(:,5),A(:,6));
scatter(time,A(:,7),1)
axis([min(time) max(time) min(A(:,7)) max(A(:,7))])
```

I found a solution here: [matlab ticks with certain labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169589/matlab-ticks-with-certain-labels) however, the process here is manual and with so much information I don't want to do this manually. How would I automate this process? or is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve?

EDIT: I also found this method: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html#btpnuk4-1, however, I dont want to show the actual date, I rather want to show intervals of time, ie an hour or 30 minutes.

EDIT 2: I have found a somewhat satisfactory solution. It could still be improved upon, so I don't know if I should submit this as an answer to my own question or not, but here it is:

```
A = dlmread('data.txt',' ');
time = datenum(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),A(:,4),A(:,5),A(:,6));
temp= time(1);
timediff = time - temp;
scatter(timediff,A(:,7),1)
axis([min(timediff) max(timediff) min(A(:,7)) max(A(:,7))])
datetick('x', 'HH')
```

This takes the original time vector in serialized time format and subtracts the first time from all the subsequent times to get the difference. The it uses the `datetick` function to to convert that to hours. It isn't ideal because instead of 24 hours it goes back to 00, but its the best I have tried thus far.

Comment: When you say "intervals", do you mean the labels should be e.g. '0-1', '1-2', '2-3'... (which doesn't really make sense if the data isn't binned in some way)

Comment: No I mean that the labels should be 0, 1, 2 ... etc. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the other article, you will have to follow the same method but in order to automate the process you'll need to form the vectors of xtick and xticklabels as you read in the data and after you've plotted the data change the xticks and xticklabels.

Its not difficult what you're trying to do, but I will need more details of how you want to organize the ticks to be able to exactly say the steps that you'd have to follow

Answer (score 0):

Matlab serial time is simply days since January 1, 0000, so your `timediff` variable is really elapsed days (and fractions thereof) since the start of your experiment. If you want your x ticks to be elapsed hours you could multiply `timediff` by 24.

```
scatter(timediff * 24, values)
```

This avoids the weirdness that can arise when using `datetick` as well.